# Facebook Actionscript API examples not compiling - application descriptor not found

Tags: facebook-graph-api, actionscript, air

Trying to run some of the desktop(AIR) samples located here
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/

No matter what I try get the error message

```
Process terminated without establishing connection to debugger.

application descriptor not found
```

But as far as I can tell there IS a proper descriptor file (XML) present in my bin-debug folder.
Anyone have an idea what is happening? Could the issue have something to do with the Flexsdk I am using (4.6) when combined with the latest AIR 3.4?

This is my application descriptor file WITHOUT most of the commented code

```
<id>MediaUploadDemo</id>


<filename>MediaUploadDemo</filename>


<name>MediaUploadDemo</name>

<version>v1</version>


<initialWindow>

    <content>MediaUploadDemo.swf</content>


</initialWindow>
```

Comment: What I tried, editing the AIR SDK version in the namespace descriptor and adding a supportedProfiles tag to equal extendedDesktop

Answer (score 0):

Found most of my answers here

http://alpha-beta-pruning.blogspot.ca/2011/06/migrating-flex-3-project-to-flex-45.html

Key paragraph 
'Each AIR sdk tends to have it's own application descriptor file formatting which means     that an application that was created with AIR 2.0 must "migrate" its descriptor file to the new AIR 2.7 sdk. My suggestion is creating from scratch a new project that targets the new sdk, just so we can take its descriptor file, copy/paste it to our "old" project and change the necessary values to adapt our project (such as project name, etc).'